# Java 7, try and catch problems? Ubuntu Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, ubuntu

Hello I am having some problems with the code below. The try and catch blocks have a red X at the try line in my IDE telling me that a "(" was encountered but a "{" was expected. Am I missing something? What could be my problem?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.StandardSocketOptions;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
/** * * @author Apress */

public class FutureForm 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int DEFAULT_PORT = 5555;
    final String IP = "127.0.0.1";
    // v-This parenthesis should be a bracket it says??
    try( AsynchronousServerSocketChannel asynchronousServerSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()) 
    {
        if (asynchronousServerSocketChannel.isOpen()) 
        {
            asynchronousServerSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(IP, DEFAULT_PORT));
            System.out.println("Waiting for connections ...");
            while (true) 
            {
                Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> asynchronousSocketChannelFuture = asynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept();
                try (AsynchronousSocketChannel asynchronousSocketChannel = asynchronousSocketChannelFuture.get()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + asynchronousSocketChannel.getRemoteAddress());
                    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
                    while (asynchronousSocketChannel.read(buffer).get() != -1) 
                    {
                        buffer.flip();
                        asynchronousSocketChannel.write(buffer).get();
                        if (buffer.hasRemaining()) 
                            buffer.compact();
                        else 
                            buffer.clear();
                    }
                    System.out.println(asynchronousSocketChannel.getRemoteAddress() + " was successfully served!");
                } 
                catch (IOException || InterruptedException || ExecutionException ex) 
                {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("The asynchronous server-socket channel cannot be opened!");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you have configured your workspace for Java 1.7, in Preferences under Java>Compiler: "Compiler compliance level."

If that doesn't help, check the project properties under Java Compiler, which should either not have project-specific settings, or have 1.7 configured.

Comment: I have my project settings to use java 1.7.0 openjdk... I did have it using Java 7 but both of them give the same error still. Any other ideas..?

Comment: Are you referring to the project settings under "Java Build Path": "Libraries", or to "Java Compiler": "JDK Compliance"?

Comment: Hm. I was not. But now that I look at the Java Compiler, JDK compliance it will only let me set it to 1.6 and not to 1.7. There is no option for me to set it to 1.7.

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have? I'm seeing 1.7 in last year's Indigo release.

Comment: version 3.7.0. I am going to try and see if there are any updates

Comment: I think you want 3.7.1, if I'm reading this Eclipse bug correctly: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288548

Comment: I will try that here in a second. I think you are right. Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if that is the reason for the warning, but you have a syntax error in your multicatch: you need to use only single pipes.

```
catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex)
```

Comment: @BumSkeeter Then it is either a configuration issue or a bug. With the correction I proposed, your code compiles and runs fine on my machine (Windows / Netbeans).

Comment: Thank you... I think I will try and find a class mate to help. We had been using java 6 for the longest time but I guess the <Future> is not in java 7. So we had to upgrade.